# C++ Singleton class creates more than one instance

Tags: c++, qt

The static method GetUI is called with mouse events, however noticed from debug that the constructor is called twice in some very rare cases with rush of mouse events.

The question is it the scheduler that halted in the middle of the construction, switching to another task process call that also started to create another instance ?

```
    Object* Interface::instance = 0;

    Object* Interface::GetUI() {
        if (instance == 0) {
            instance = new Interface();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: you can use mutex to lock.

Comment: Look up "Meyer's Singleton". And then learn not to use singletons.

Comment: If you're using Qt, I think there are some macros in the library to create thread-safe singletons. I think `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC` is what you're looking for, but I don't know if that's public (stable) API.

Comment: good advice (offtopic): singletons are a curse avoid them.

Comment: you are writing about mouse events so this shouldn't be a multithreading issue, evrything should happen on main thread. Add assertion `Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() == QCoreApplication::instance()->thread())` to make sure that this is a problem (if it fails check call stack). I recommend also disable assign operator and copy constructor.

Comment: @MarekR He hasn't mentioned `QT`, but it's a good point anyway.  I would expect mouse events to all occur in the same thread.  (Of course, he may be dispatching them from the main thread to other threads, in which case, the problem could be threading.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: see tags he used: Qt.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for help, will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should actually lock the singleton, otherwise, when multithreading, you will create multiple instances.
for C++11, you can use it as below.

```
#include <mutex>

class Singleton 
{
    static Singleton *singletonInstance;
    Singleton() {}
    static std::mutex m_;

    public:

    static Singleton* getSingletonInstance()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
        if(singletonInstance == nullptr)
        {
            singletonInstance = new Singleton();
        }
        return singletonInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: This defeats one of the goals of a `Singleton`, since it can result in order of initialization issues.  (I doubt that it will be a problem in his case, however; if the singleton is only used when handling mouse events, it won't be called before static initialization have finished.)

Comment: @JamesKanze How does it result in "order of initialization issues"? The use of `std::mutex` as shown is IIRC perfectly kosher. This code is guaranteed to set `singletonInstance` with the address of the newly constructed `Singleton` exactly once. About the only dubious thing might be a missing memory fence, but presumably that's implied in the release of the mutex. That's really about the only issue that stands out to me.

Comment: why aren't you unlocking the mutex?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you describe can only appear when the `GetUI` is used from multiple threads. I hope you are aware that you can't do any direct calls on GUI methods without proper locking or using the queued method invocation.

The thread-safe, idiomatic way of creating global variables in Qt is shown below. There's really no reason for a yet another implementation of it. Sometimes NIH is bad.

```
#include <QtGlobal>

class Object {};
class Interface {
public:
   static Object * GetUI();
};

// This must be in a *single* source file *only*. Not in header!
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(Object, interfaceInstance)

Object* Interface::GetUI() {
    return interfaceInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a race condition between the
creation and the instantiation of the object.  There are two
possible solutions; you can synchronize the `GetUI` function,
as Jerry YY suggested, or you can ensure that the singleton is
created before you start threading; a race condition only occurs
when you modify the object in at least one thread, and once
you've created the object, `instance` is never modified.

One way of doing this is to simply define `Interface::instance`
as:

```
Object* Interface::instance = Interface::GetUI();
```

Zero initialization ensures that before `Interface::GetUI` is
called, `Interface::instance` is initialized to the null
pointer, and the initialization of static objects takes place
before `main`.

Otherwise: if you're sure that `Interface::GetUI` will never be
called before entering `main` (which seems likely, given what
you've said—there shouldn't be any mouse events before you
enter `main`), then you can drop the test (or replace it with
`assert( instance != nullptr` ) in `Interface::GetUI`, and just
write:

```
Object* Interface::instance = new Interface();
```

Much simpler, and avoids all of the problems.

Comment: Can you point to where in the standard it's claimed that zero initialization happens for such objects? I've always thought (perhaps erroneously) that it's not guaranteed for explicitly initizalized objects - heck, it'd be a tad wasteful, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nicer singleton implementation with templating:

```
template <class T>
class Singleton 
{
private:
  static T * _instance;
protected:
  Singleton (){}
public:
  static T & get()
  {
    if (_instance)
    {
      return *_instance;
    }
    _instance = new T();
    return *_instance;
  }
};

template <class T>  T* Singleton<T>::_instance = 0;
```

Now implement it with inheritance:

```
class Foo : public Singleton<Foo>
```

And utilize it anywhere:

```
Foo::get().DoSomething();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is faster version of [earlier solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23778561/1387438) (reduces use of mutex overhead).

```
#include <mutex>

class Singleton 
{
    static volatile Singleton * singletonInstance;
    Singleton() {}
    static std::mutex m_;

    public:

    static Singleton* getSingletonInstance()
    {
        if(singletonInstance == nullptr)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
            if(singletonInstance == nullptr) {
                Singleton *tmp = new Singleton(); // fight with compiler see link in comment
                singletonInstance = tmp;
            }
        }
        return singletonInstance;
    }
}
```

Anyway I'm not convinced that multithreading is a problem, since you've wrote about mouse events and this should come only from main thread.
Add assertion `Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() == QCoreApplication::instance()->thread())` to make sure that this is a problem with synchronization (if it fails check a call stack).

I recommend also disable assign operator and copy constructor.

Comment: It also doesn't work.  If any thread modifies an object, then no thread may access it without synchronization.  You might want to read http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf.

Comment: thanks for link I have to read why this `tmp` variable is needed.

Comment: Not only the `tmp` variable, but memory barriers or fences.  (Alternatively, with C++11, I think making `instance` atomic should be sufficient.)

Comment: The `singletonInstance` may be non-null yet not fully written into. Say only 32 bits out of a 64 bit value may be written. I find attempts at reinventing this highly suspicious. The solution offered by Qt itself is tested and known to work. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score -3):

Your instance and your GetUI() method must be static.

Comment: The instance and GetUI() are static.